# Validate Authorization in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

My roles are dynamic and their User's permission are also dynamic. I have two approaches to validate if the user is authorized to access the particular page.

**Approach 1**

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        if(!\Auth::user()->IsPredefined) {
            $result = $this->ValidateAuthorization();
            if(!$result) {
                \Auth::logout();
                return redirect()->route("login");
            }
        }
    }

    private function ValidateAuthorization() {
        $ActionName = \Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
        switch ($ActionName) {
            case "ChangePassword":
                $ModuleID = ModuleEnum::AccountManagemenet;
                $ActionID = AccountActionEnum::ChangePassword;
                return CheckUsePermissions($ModuleID, $ActionID);            
        }
    }

    private function CheckUsePermissions($ModuleID, $ActionID) {
        $User = MySession::UserPermissions();
        foreach($User->UserRolePermissions as $UserRolePermission) {
            $CurrentActionID = $UserRolePermission->RolePermission->Permission->ActionID;
            $CurrentModuleID = $UserRolePermission->RolePermission->Permission->ModuleID;
            if($CurrentActionID == $ActionID && $CurrentModuleID == $ModuleID && 
                    $UserRolePermission->IsActive == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**

Use Authorize method in Request class

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

**Confusion**

1. If Approach 2 is good, should I create Request class for each Get, Put, Delete and POST?
2. Is there any better approach to validate authorization?

Comment: you should use middleware

Comment: My roles will be created dynamically. Role's permission will be assigned dynamically. So I have no idea which role will have which permission. Please suggest.

Comment: jsut do it like you are doing in controller but do it in middleware class so then you don't need to write it again or again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Dynamic Roles I do something like this:

Let suppose I have following permissions:

1. Manage Users
2. Manage CMS
3. Manage Hotels
4. Manage Packages
5. Manage Roles

Now the `Super Admin` (who obviously has all the above permissions) can create a role, say, `Hotel Manager` and assign permission for only `Manage Hotels`.

Now for a route like:

```
Route::get('/admin/hotels', 'HotelsController@index')->name('admin.hotels.index');
```

I will put it in a `Route Group` with a middleware in it:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/admin/hotels', 'middleware' => ['permission:manage_hotels']], function () {
  Route::get('/', 'HotelsController@index')->name('admin.hotels.index');
  Route::post('/', 'HotelsController@create')->name('admin.hotels.create');
});
```

Then I will create a `Permission` middleware:

```
class Permission
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission)
  { 
   //if not super admin (super admin role_id is 1)
   if(auth()->user()->role_id != 1) {
   //explode extra param passed to this middleware (here manage_hotels)
   $permission_array = explode('_', $permission);

   foreach ($permission_array as $key => $value) {
     $permission_array[$key] = ucfirst($value);
   }

   $permission_name = implode(' ', $permission_array);

   $permitted = auth()->user()->role->permissions()->where('name', $permission_name)->first();

   if(! $permitted) {
    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard')->withErrors(['error' => ['message' => 'You are not allowed to perform this action.']]);
   }
  }

  return $next($request);
  }
 }
```

Of course you'll need to wrap these routes into `Admin Middleware` which will ensure that user is logged in and has an admin role.

Comment: can u please explain more in details about `'middleware' => ['permission:manage_hotels']]` ? I have understood that `Permission` class will be `Middleware`. But what is `permission:manage_hotels` ?

Comment: With middleware name Anything that you write after : in this case `manage_hotels` will be available in the `handle` method of that middleware.

Comment: Have a look at middleware parameters https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should use middleware and use in routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () { });
```

Or you can use in every controller constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

Admin middleware like

```
class AdminAuthenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->IsPredefined) {
                 $result = $this->ValidateAuthorization();
                 if(!$result) {
                      return redirect('/logout');
                 }
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, You did not get my point carefully. My roles will be created dynamically. My role's permission will be created dynamically and user will be assigned a roles and assigned role's permissions. So everything is dynamic. Now tell me , how will I get to know that there is role called admin exists or not.

Comment: Add this ValidateAuthorization function on AdminAuthenticate (You can change the name) file then pass the all routes by this middlewear